# How to get KDE4 for building a project in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, qt-creator, kde4

There is a command

```
find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
```

in the CMakeLists.txt file from the question [How to make a project of Krusader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485386/how-to-make-a-project-of-krusader). My attempts to build the project in the Qt Creator result in a message

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:98 (MESSAGE):
  ERROR: cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake not found in
  /home/me_user/.kde/share/apps;/usr/share/kde4/apps
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

What particular should I install into the Ubuntu 12.04 to satisfy the line 'find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)'? (I asked about the same problem in [Qt build in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331204/qt-build-in-ubuntu-12-04); I gave it up at that time, but it appears to be a basic matter.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Build depends**

The Krusader 'Build-Depends': http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/krusader/krusader_2.4.0~beta3-2.dsc

=> cmake, debhelper (>= 9), kdelibs5-dev (>= 4:4.4.4), libkonq5-dev, pkg-kde-tools (>= 0.9.0), zlib1g-dev

The KDE development packages are: kdelibs5-dev and libkonq5-dev

Comment: I begin with building such projects, please advise me with more details how to install the required KDE4 files. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean ? How to install a package or How to find the required packages ? The Ubuntu has: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware . If you unpack the Krusader source and open the 'Install' text file you will see the list of the required packages under the 'Compilation requirements'

Comment: I meant especially 'How to find the required packages'; but studying your references shows that they are precisely what I have meant by the 'general introduction how to make such projects'.

Answer (score 1):

According to the 'Compilation requirements' (thanks to comment by user26687), kdelibs5-dev is required. In the Synaptic it was marked as not installed (no green mark) and supported (Red Ubuntu symbol). I have installed it by

```
me_user@myCPU:~$ sudo apt-get install kdelibs5-dev
```

. After it the command

```
find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
```

is accepted by Qt.